# Problems installing RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

I have tried installing Restkit to my project, but I am getting too many errors, and I don't know why, because I installed Restkit to another project last week.
I've followed every step of the tutorial in its web, and when I import Restkit and compile, I get the following errors:

[image: Screenshot errors]

Below that, another message appears: 
"Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 Error"
"Too many errors emitted, stopping now"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I was importing Restkit in the .m and it must be in the .h